# How to read a CSV file from FTP using C#

Tags: c#, .net, csv, ftp, c#-3.0

I am able to pass the authentication but i am not sure how can i read a CSV file. Link normally from a hard drive i am reading like this .

```
string[] allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\CSV\data.csv");
```

But how can i read from the ftp . My Ftp path is like that ftp://ftp.atozfdc.com.au/data.csv
Here is my code to pass ftp authentication.

```
String ftpserver = "ftp://ftp.atozfdc.com.au/data.csv";
reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpserver));
reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
reqFTP.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
```

Comment: do you need Proxy credentials to connect to your ftp? Any exceptions when you try this code?

Comment: i am not getting any error i am asking how to get a file path for example from my local computer i pass my file path like this System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\CSV\data.csv");

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
//use the response like below
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
string[] allLines = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this [link](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/built-in-net-csv-parser/)

---

`TextFieldParser` is in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace. Hence you need to add reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`

```
String path = @"D:\CSV\data.csv";

using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(path))
{
    parser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

    // if you want to skip over header line., uncomment line below
    // parser.ReadLine();

    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
        column1 = fields[0];
        column2 = fields[1];
        column3 = int.Parse(fields[2]);
        column4 = double.Parse(fields[3]);
    }
}
```

---

I would suggest you to download the file to a temporary location, and then use the temp file path to parse the CSV.

but if you do not want to create temp file then try using the `ResponseStream`

Example:

```
String ftpserver = "ftp://ftp.atozfdc.com.au/data.csv";
reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpserver));
reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
reqFTP.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();


Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
// use the stream to read file from remote location

using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(responseStream))
{
    // usual csv reader implementation
}

responseStream.Close();
response.Close(); //Closes the connection to the server
```

Comment: thanks alot i can parse a CSV file. This is not my question i am saying right now i am reading CSV from my local computer and its working fine but i want to read a file from ftp server and i have uploaded my csv on ftp and i am able to pass all the authentication but i am not sure how to get a ftp file path. so that i can replace @"D:\CSV\data.csv"; this line to ftp server csv

Answer (score 0):

ftp://ftp.atozfdc.com.au/data.csv this is your ftp file path. what else are you looking for? if you want to read the file then use

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
string[] allLines = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```